# Making a dataframe out of a for loop

Tags: r, variables, for-loop, save

I thought many times before posting this, it is really simple but I couldn't find a way to do that, sorry if it is very basic.

I am trying to find a simple command to output a dataframe that includes 2 columns, the value resulting from a for loop, along with the variable name in that loop, here's the command I am using

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {

          k <- i*5

         ##### saving the values that comes out of the loop

    if (exists("v")== "TRUE" ) {
    v= append(v,k)
    }
    if (exists("v")== "FALSE"){
    v <- k
    }

         ###### adding the name of the column

      n <- names(x[i])


    if (exists("m")== "TRUE" ) {
    m= append(m,n)
    }
    if (exists("m")== "FALSE"){
    m <- n
    }
}
         ###### I manually put them into a dataframe and bind them

         v <- data.frame(v)
         m <- data.frame(m)

         df <- cbind(v,m)
```

the output data frame I am looking for:

```
       v           m
       5         MUYC
       10        KJIO
       15        KLGJ
```

I know this is retarded, the command actually works!! I am sure there are simpler ways to write this! I just couldn't find ones so far.

here's a simple reproducible example

### the x matrix

```
structure(list(MUYC = 1555L, KJIO = 320L, KLGJ = 5132L), .Names = c("MUYC", 
"KJIO", "KLGJ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Please make your code [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) and edit an actual question into your post.

Comment: What are x, v, m, n at the beginning?

Comment: Prepopulate your data.frame, then fill values into it using `[row,column]` indices, or use something from the `*apply` family instead of `for`.

Comment: @Roland, I is this reproducible?

Comment: @shadow, x is the matrix I have, v,m and n are defined in the above program.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors. It seems like you want `cbind.data.frame(v=seq_along(names(x))*5, m=names(x))` which indeed seems a bit silly. Also, you don't habe a `matrix`. It's a `data.frame`.

Comment: The first line of your for-loop isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Ok, now the loop is working fine

Comment: @Roland yes your command does the same, but why do you consider it silly?

Comment: @Error404 Probably because I don't know the context.

Comment: @Error404 here is a tip for next time - a question that takes 10 comments and 3 edits to become barely understandable will not attract many good answers. Focus on making a toy [**reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) that illustrates the crux of the problem without unnecessary detail that makes it harder to understand the problem (i.e. it doesn't have to be your actual code - make a simple example up instead).

Comment: @SimonO101, Thanks for your kind comment. This is exactly what I did above, sorry for the multiple edits. My command is doing alright, I was just thinking of a more professional, reliable way to write this. The problem here is simply that it is taking me a half page of command to save an output of a 2-line for loop. But seems like I am going to stick the command I have above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind it seems all your want to do is this:

```
data.frame( v = seq( from = 5 , by = 5 , length.out = length(x) ) , m = names(x) )
#   v    m
#1  5 MUYC
#2 10 KJIO
#3 15 KLGJ
```

But I don't know how generalisable to your problem this will be.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I can edit this to fit the data I have. Cheers (Y)